# Python not copying variable user-defined class but making pointer instead

Tags: python, class, chess

I was trying to make chess playing algorithm that "bruteforces" possible options and choosing the best.

To do this, I wrote class, which represents board situation on board(showed the parts that used in bad code).

```py
class Chess:
    def __init__(self):
        #Here is the board 2D array - enemy is downside.
        self.board = [[ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, BISHOP, KNIGHT, ROOK], [PAWN for i in range(8)], [EMPTY for i in range(8)], [EMPTY for i in range(8)], [EMPTY for i in range(8)], [EMPTY for i in range(8)], [ENEMYPAWN for i in range(8)], [ENEMYROOK, ENEMYKNIGHT, ENEMYBISHOP, ENEMYKING, ENEMYQUEEN, ENEMYBISHOP, ENEMYKNIGHT, ENEMYROOK]]

    def WriteBoard(self):
        WriteBoard(self.board)

    def Moove(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        if x1 >= 8 or x1 < 0 or x2 >= 8 or x2 < 0 or y1 >= 8 or y1 < 0 or y2 >= 8 or y2 < 0:
            raise IndexError("Parameter is not correct.")
            return
        #WARNING: Not checking if moove correct.
        self.board[y2][x2] = self.board[y1][x1]
        self.board[y1][x1] = EMPTY
```

Where:

```
EMPTY = 0

PAWN = 2
ROOK = 17
KNIGHT = 10
BISHOP = 14
QUEEN = 45
KING = 60

ENEMYPAWN = -2
ENEMYROOK = -17
ENEMYKNIGHT = -10
ENEMYBISHOP = -14
ENEMYQUEEN = -45
ENEMYKING = -60
```

...Next part is function that returns possible moves getting Chess variable and x, y as parameters:

```py
def PossibleMooves(chessBoard, x, y):
    possibleMooves = []
    target = chessBoard.board[y][x]
    if target == EMPTY:
        return possibleMooves
    helpVar = chessBoard

    if target == PAWN:
        try:
            if helpVar.board[y + 1][x] == EMPTY:
                helpVar.Moove(x, y, x, y + 1)
                possibleMooves += [res]
                index += 1
                helpVar = chessBoard
        except IndexError as e:
            ... #print(e)
    elif target == ROOK:
        ...
    ... #And so on...
    return possibleMooves
```

Please note that try...except statement helps to establish correctness of move(index like [y + 1][x] can not exist)

### But the problem is:

> Variable *chessBoard* changing together with *helpVar*, and variable that were given to function.

You can check it with this code:

```py
chess = Chess()

print(chess.board[1][1])
results = PossibleMooves(chess, 1, 1)
print(chess.board[1][1])
```

Output should be:

> 2 
> 2

But its:

> 2 
> 0

Answer (score 1):

`helpVar = chessBoard` means that every change you make to `helpVar` will be reflected in `chessBoard`. They point to the same object. If you want to avoid it - clone chessBoard and work with a copy.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html) about `copy` in python. (Look at [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy))